# Megohmmeter, Insulation tester, megger

Tags: voltage, current, insulation, tester

Can anyone please explain how does megohmmeter (insulation tester) work.
Here is what I don't I don't understand:

1. These little tester can produce e.g. 1000V, how is that done? What are the  internals that can produce I assume from 9V battery 1000V?
2. How can something generate 1000V at very low current? Internal resistance? From what I understand if you increase voltage you also increase current. If you trying to produce 1000V and put a big resistor in the front of it to lower the current, don't you immediately lower the voltage as well?

Two basic questions how does the internal of the meter work and how can you produce 1000V with little current.

I am clearly missing some basics.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny Stepup transformer can easily generate 1kV or even 5kV from an oscillator with centre tapped 9V. With a primary impedance  \$Zp, ~~Zout=Zp*n^2\$ so that for example with 1:200 turns ratio and < 1 Ohm (switches + battery ESR+ primary winding DCR) becomes \$200^2=40k\$ which unregulated can give 200*9V= 1.8kV but regulated to  1kV or more rectified for DC testing is possible.

If primary was not current limited, Short cct. current(SCC) could be 50mA and  primary could be 200*50mA = 10A, so it is current limited on input , so that  output current (I expect)  is limited 1mA which is adequate for insulation test with BDV < 1kV.

add:  I see MEGGER products have both crank and 12V AA operation with 0.5 to 5kV selections ~ 1.5mA  +/-0.5

What does your tester specify or SCC?

Comment: Step transformer - understood. The rest of the text looks  bit scientific, I am not an engineer. Can you elaborate in simple terms how is it possible to generate 1000V with little current?

Comment: Why do you ask then?  A tiny ignition coil can generate 35kV V=LdI/dt

Comment: No I mean how is it possible to generate 1000V with little current. Example: 300V electric car battery if touched will go through 1000Ohm human body resistor and produce about 0.3A - potentially fatal. What If the 1000V of insulation tester will be will be touched and produce on human skin? Is that dangerous, or do these tester provide very little current, if so how is that done? What I understand higher voltage will equal higher current.

Comment: If a finger is 100k and when it ionizes it can reduce down to 1k and then the follow on current would be in this example 300V/1k= 300 mA.  the insulation breakdown gap for air is about 3kV/mm so the finger would have to almost touch the 1kV with 0.3mm gap to get zapped if say another part of the body was battery ground.  The inuslation tester only produces about 1mA by current limit design  so it would be felt but would not harm a healthy person.  The difference is the source resistance of the voltage source.

Comment: An e-car battery if it had 1kV that might be very powerful and generate 100kW of power would have a resistance in the order of xxx micro-ohms while a Megger is design to be high resistance of 1M and limit the current to approx 1mA. This about 10 orders of magnitude difference in source resistance.